# Java swing, creating a button in my paint component

Tags: java, swing, button, layout

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
    g.drawImage(back,0,0,this);

    if(winner || loser){

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(new Font(null,Font.BOLD,55));
        g.drawString("SCORE:",350,250);
        g.drawString(""+score,600,250);
        g.drawImage(enemy,100,500,this);
        g.drawImage(enemy2,175,500,this);
        g.drawImage(enemy3,250,500,this);
        g.drawImage(enemy5,700,515,this);
        g.drawImage(enemy6,775,515,this);
        g.drawImage(enemy7,850,515,this);
        g.drawImage(enemy4,495,515,this);
        if(winner){
            g.drawImage(winnerPic,200,50,this); 
        }
        else{
            g.drawImage(gameOver,220,50,this);
        }
        g.drawImage(endingTitle,190,590,this);

        JButton menu=new JButton("Return to menu");
        menu.setSize(200,100);
        menu.setLocation(400,400);
    }
}
```

How do I make a button appear on the screen. Please be very detailed, idk how to work with swings layout styles.

Comment: Don't update or modify the state of the component from within the paintComponent method

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have a container (such as a JPanel for example) that is displayed on a JFrame.
After crating your button, you have to add it to the container. Most of the time you want your container to have a Layout, such as a BorderLayout.

```
JButton menu = new JButton("Back to the menu");
container.add(menu, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

EDIT:
If this isn't the way you want to implement it, it will atleast help you understand the hierarchy.

```
public void buttonExample(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

    JButton button = new JButton("Return to the menu");
    panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: how do you define a container and after you add the button to the container, how will it appear to the screen.

Comment: @ShadowKing That's just really basic Swing, see how [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)